# Procedimiento SQL con tablas sin relación

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Necesito hacer un procedimiento almacenado en SQL con tres tablas sin relación: '`ingreso`, `gasto`, `gastoVarios`', tengo que mostrar el total de `montoFactIngreso`, de `montoFactGasto` y de `montoFactVarios` en una columna cada total, usé este **select** pero me muestra los totales en una única columna:

```
SELECT SUM(ingreso.montoFactIngreso)
FROM   ingreso
UNION
SELECT SUM(gasto.montoFactGasto)
FROM   gasto
UNION
SELECT SUM(gastoVarios.montoFactVarios)
FROM   gastoVarios
```

[image: Tablas a usar en el procedimiento]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para esto puedes usar simplemente `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT  G.Gasto,
        I.Ingreso,
        V.Varios
FROM (  SELECT SUM(montoFactGasto) Gasto
        FROM dbo.gasto) G
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(montoFactIngreso) Ingreso
            FROM dbo.ingreso) I
CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(montoFactVarios) Varios
            FROM dbo.gastoVarios) V;
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: Hola @DanielNavarroSaborío si esta respuesta te ha sido de utilidad, sugiero que des clic en la marca de respuesta aceptada `✓`, así como el voto arriba `▲` que se encuentran en la parte izquierda de la respuesta de Lamak. ¡Saludos!